# Things that has to be taken care for exception utility classes

Tags: java, exception

We are creating an Exception utility class which can process any exception occurring in   code. Each catch block in any class will call the utility class and the utility class has to write to log files, send email to admin and show status codes to user. Anything else I can do from this  exception utility class apart from these activities.

Comment: I think your approach is wrong: you should let the excepton propagate up the call stack instead of catching and handling everywhere. There are but a few places in code where you would have to actually repeat the handling code.

Comment: You're doing the wrong thing. You should handle each exception in the place where it can be handled. That's context-dependent. If error handling was really as simple as your design assumes, there wouldn't be any need for exceptions or even errors at all.

Comment: Our primary aim is to inform admin user.  Apart from this how we can enhance the utility class? I know it is a broad question but welcomes to any idea

Comment: Agreed with Marko and you can probably create utility to log the exception in the file using Log4j or other similar utility.

Comment: I am fine with this approach. My primary focus is anything else I need to do  apart from  1) loging to files. 2) sending emails.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to go out on a limb ...

I think what you are doing is a bad idea:

- Your utility class should not be writing to log files.  It should be sending log events to a logging subsystem (java.util.logging, log4j, logback, slf4j, etc.) and leaving it to the logging subsystem to decide what to log.
- Your utility class should not be generating emails.  If you are going to do that kind of thing, it is best to disconnect that from the application entirely.  For example, implement something to scan the log files ... or process log events.

  There are sophisticated systems that are designed for doing this without filling the admin's mail box, etc with useless error reports.  Look up "nagios" and "zenoss" for some examples ...

The main advantage of using logging subsystem and external monitoring is that you can change the behaviour in configuration files rather than having to modify, build and redeploy your code.

Comment: +1 for the second point... and I'm sure every admin is capable enough to route these error alerts straight to /dev/null.

Comment: I am fine with this approach. My primary focus is anything else I need to do apart from 1) loging to files. 2) sending emails

Answer (score 0):

if you have a client-server-architecture then you might have two different exception handling strategies. On server side logging is necessary, but on client side additional messaging to the server should at least be considered. Also keep in mind that on client side (in UI interface) messages can be sent to UI as dialog boxes or information panels, but on server side not. So your exception utility class maybe split into two different classes.

And above all: I would think about catching exceptions. General strategy must be throwing, not catching. If your architecture catches exceptions then think very well, where this should happen.

Comment: I require only server side exception handling utilities currently

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions to improve your class

1. Don't write such a class. Exception handling should either

   1. ignore exception and let them travel up the stack until somebody can properly handle them.
   2. properly handle them according to the context in which they appear. This has to happen once for each context, so a priori there shouldn't be much code duplication
2. Don't let it do what you described: If you have to log something use your logging library (sl4j, log4j, whatever) If you want e-mails for some of those log entries configure an apropriate appender. Some exceptions you want to display to the user, but hopefully those are special exceptions, intended for that purpose, that get handled in one special place (e.g. a servlet filter in Java Servlet based application)
3. Don't name the class like this
   Hopefully every class in your project is useful (i.e. a utility) (Hint: if not delete it). Therefore you should't really have any class with the suffix "Util" or similar

Comment: Disagree with point 3: there is a whole pattern called the *Utility class* and usually it's called... `Util`. You can read it is a noname, general-purpose repository of global functions and objects.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I think you forget a "anti" before the word pattern. :-)

Comment: Not sure why Utility classes are anti pattern!!? Do you have any of your work in a public repo others can take a look at?